# Improve SEM sharpness image

Tags: image-processing, image

Hello Mathematica experts :)

I have some SEM images of the nano-particles. However, the technician can not get better results.

With Mathematica image treatment, could we improve to get higher quality (sharp, clear) SEM?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6790V.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWCMT.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyNGU.jpg

The desired result should clear like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mh5w.jpg

Comment: Hm... You could play around a bit with `GaussianFilter` or `Sharpen`...

Comment: Thank you. I've tried but didn't get the desired quality.

Comment: I am a bit wary of this process. Doing something like this in my field of research could be construed as misconduct. Enhancing scientific figures is dangerous business. You should tread carefully and make sure that the procedure is acceptable in your field. Higher resolution can be obtained with similar samples, as shown by the desirable image you include.

Comment: You may use `ImageDeconvolve`. [Here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ImageDeconvolution/) is a demonstration. If you exchange the example pictures with yours, you see if it helps.